# bootstrap datatables update e delete usando firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, datatable, realtime-database

Como faço atualização e remoção de dados de uma tabela (estou usando o Datatables Bootstrap) com o firebase realtime database?

[image: Nós filhos do pai "Locais"]

[image: Datatables do Bootstrap 4]
Obs: O ícone do pincel é para editar os dados e o da lixeira para excluir. Porém não funcionam ainda.

[image: Preenche a tabela]

[image: Jquery para excluir dos dados]
Obs: Quando clico no ícone de exclusão não exclui do firebase, como resolver?

**O jquery do atualizar não sei como fazer**. Alguém me ajuda, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

note que idLocal não é um child de "Locais" e sim um atributo de um objeto.

de acordo com sua foto sua árvore é *root - >Locais -> -MjWklrQo80Ra3RKvZhl*

você pode acessar a chave a propriedade .key do datasnapshot
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md#datasnapshotkey

```
const data = snapshot.val(); // Dados dentro do child
const key = snapshot.key; // chave. ex: MjWklrQo80Ra3RKvZhl
dbRef.child("Locais").child(key).remove();
```

Comment: Obrigada Paulo.